# Is it possible to use data from state A inside a selector in state B?

Tags: ngxs

I am trying out Ngxs as a state management system and came across a specific use case that I can't seem to figure out. In this use case I am using two **normalized** objects (I removed some unnecessary fields for readability).

```
export interface Section {
  id: number;
  sequence: number;
  name: string;
  subName: string;
  totalQuestions: number;
  completedQuestions: number;
  selected: boolean;
  questionFlows: QuestionFlow[];
}

export interface QuestionFlow {
  id: number;
  contractId: number;
  parentId: number;
  subSectionId: number;
  path: string;
  question: string;
  type: string;
  answer: string;
  completed: boolean;
  sequenceNumber: number;
  selected: boolean;
  questionFlows: QuestionFlow[];
}
```

These two objects reside in separate stores. A SectionStore and a QuestionFlowStore. The state models are like follows:

```
export class SectionsStateModel {
  sections: { [id: number]: Section };
  currentSection: Section;
}

export class QuestionFlowsStateModel {
  questionFlows: { [id: number]: QuestionFlow };
  currentQuestionFlow: QuestionFlow;
}
```

Now I would like to create a selector in the QuestionFlowsState that returns every questionFlow that belongs to the currentSection. Is it possible to get the currentSection inside a selector that resides inside the QuestionFlowState while the currentSection resides inside the SectionState? I have tried the code below (with a filled store) without success.

```
import { SectionsStateModel } from './sections.state';

@State<QuestionFlowsStateModel>({
  name: 'questionFlows',
  defaults: {
    questionFlows: {},
    currentQuestionFlow: null
  }
})
export class QuestionFlowsState {
  @Selector()
  static getQuestionFlowsArrayFromCurrentSection(
    state: QuestionFlowsStateModel,
    sectionState: SectionsStateModel
  ) {
    const questionFlowsFromCurrentSection: QuestionFlow[] = [];

    sectionState.currentSection.questionFlows.forEach(questionFlow => {
      questionFlowsFromCurrentSection.push(state.questionFlows[+questionFlow]);
    });

    return questionFlowsFromCurrentSection;
  }
}
```

If there is anything missing/unclear in the question, please let me know.

EDIT:
[After some back and forth with @Danny Blue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49878054/9658262) we've come to the solution of adding a parent state that takes the states that contain the data needed for the selector as children (which can be set in the @State decorator). To access the data from these children stores you'll need to call the state.. and you are good to go. Below is the final code that solves my problem.

```
import { State, Selector } from '@ngxs/store';

import { SectionsState } from './sections.state';
import { QuestionFlowsState } from './question-flows.state';
import { QuestionFlow } from '../../contract-details.model';
import { SectionsStateModel } from './sections.state';
import { QuestionFlowsStateModel } from './question-flows.state';

@State({
  name: 'parent',
  children: [SectionsState, QuestionFlowsState]
})
export class ParentState {
  @Selector()
  static getParentFlowsArrayFromCurrentSection(
    state
  ) {
    const questionFlowsFromCurrentSection: QuestionFlow[] = [];

    state.sections.currentSection.questionFlows.forEach(questionFlow => {
      questionFlowsFromCurrentSection.push(
        state.questionFlows.questionFlows[+questionFlow]
      );
    });

    return questionFlowsFromCurrentSection;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the selector at a parent state class which would give it access to both child state.

https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/advanced/sub-states

Comment: Do you mean that I should add another state with both the SectionState and the QuestionFlowState as children, or just add the QuestionFlowState as a child of SectionState?
I tried adding a new state with both as children and add the selector over there but that didn't seem to solve it. Same goes for adding the QuestionFlowState as child in the SectionState.

Comment: yes I was thinking of adding a new state class and making both children of that. can you share the code where making them children did not work?

Comment: I've added the code I used to test what (I thought) you meant with your answer.

Comment: So the argument passing into the selector will be one object with both properties on it. not two arguments

Comment: I've edited the code to only pass one state object. But this doesn't seem to fix it. Could it be that it doesn't work because I am using an array object which doesn't work with substates according to: https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/advanced/sub-states#caveats

Comment: can you share a repo with the code? or a stackblitz. would make it easier to help

Comment: Sure. All the code is on my github: https://github.com/Koen967/NgXs-learning. There are multiple branches where I tried some different solutions. The branch where I tried the solution you provided is on the ParentState branch.

Comment: @Koen967 that should work. log out the state in one of the parent selectors. I doesn't look like you are accessing the object correctly

Comment: for example state.currentSection would be state.sections.currectSection

Comment: @Koen967 there actually a very similar question on the slack channel. https://now-examples-slackin-eqzjxuxoem.now.sh/

Comment: So when calling the data from a child state inside the parent state you'll need to call the name of the child state before accessing the data. Changing the call to state.sections.currentSection like you said seems to work. I'll edit in the final code in my question and will mark this as the answer. Thanks for the help @Danny Blue